# can't install pandas in anaconda3: No Space left on device

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda3

i had checked my drive with code: df -H and i see my drive have 4TB free. But when i install pandas, it have error: No Space left on device
my code is: pip install pandas
[image]
Is there any way to fix this error? Thanks

i had try delete some env, but still showing the same error message as above

Comment: This isn't a programming issue. You can ask on [unix.se] instead. But FWIW, the device might be out of inodes; I think that can cause that error. Or you might be installing to the wrong drive/partition.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)